# Add Win7 install to Ubuntu (dual-boot)

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

I have decided I want my netbook (Acer D270) to be able to boot to Windows, besides my current Linux (Kubuntu) install.

The thing I've learned in the past is if you want a dual boot system you should install Linux last, as it's able to handle other systems gracefully while Windows tends to be a bully and delete/overwrite/damage them. It's been several years since I made a dual-boot system though and I hope the situation has changed since then - and I'll be able to add a second partition for Win7 without need to reinstall my Kubuntu.

Now, how do I approach it to minimize the chance of Windows 7 erasing my OS? (besides making a backup obviously) Are there any specific steps/operations I need to take to ensure Win7 installs to a new partition I create for it (after resizing Linux partition using a LiveCD distribution) instead of wiping everything?

(note this is a netbook, so I'll need to use USB pendrive-based install.)

Comment: Just create the parition in Kubuntu the select the same parition when you install Windows.  If you are careful then it cannot and will not touch any other parition.

Comment: @Ramhound: It will almost certainly touch the boot sector though...

Comment: If you want to dual boot you want that.

Comment: @SF.: Windows will overwrite the boot loader/GRUB, but won't touch the Linux partition (it's never done that). Just install it and then run Boot-Repair from a Linux LiveCD/USB to restore Grub and add Windows to the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

  Create partitions for Windows 7 using GParted in Ubuntu.

  Boot the Windows 7 disk and install it on the partition created in the previous step. (Windows will not provide you with the option of choosing Ubuntu). So Ubuntu would seem unusable.

  Recover Ubuntu by using a live CD (or live USB) and following the steps mentioned in Ask Ubuntu question Recovering GRUB after installing Windows 7 (at the end, you should have the option of choosing the operating system from the GRUB menu.)

Comment: Why don't you link directly to the Ask Ubuntu question?